# Read Config map in Angular timing is of

Tags: angular, environment-variables

I followed [this](https://ychetankumarsarma.medium.com/how-to-manage-angular-application-configurations-for-different-environments-with-docker-and-8ff8c55a1c7d) tutorial to set my URL dynamically in my Kubernetes cluster.

The thing is when I run the container in my Kubernetes cluster it applies the `env.js` and when I look in my network tab it is the correct value, but the environment.service.ts is still using the "development" input that I hardcoded in the `env.js`.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

env.js

```
(function(window) {
  window.__env = window.__env || {};
  // Define your environment variables
  window.__env.API_URL = "[DEVELOPMENT URL]";
})(this);
```

env_token.js

```
(function (window) {
  window.__env = window.__env || {};
  window.__env.API_URL = "${API_URL}";
})(this);
```

environment.service.provider.ts

```
import {EnviromentService} from "./enviroment.service";

declare global {
  interface Window { __env: {[key: string]: string}; }
}

const EnvServiceFactory = () => {
  const env = new EnviromentService();

  // Read environment variables from the browser window
  const browserWindowEnv = window.__env || {};

  // Assign environment variables from the browser window to env
  // In the current implementation, properties from env.js overwrite defaults from the EnvService.
  // If needed, a deep merge can be performed here to merge properties instead of overwriting them.
  for (const key in browserWindowEnv) {
    //{API_URL: ""}
    if (browserWindowEnv.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      env.API_URL = browserWindowEnv[key];
    }
  }

  return env;
};

export const EnvServiceProvider = {
  provide: EnviromentService,
  useFactory: EnvServiceFactory,
  deps: [],
};
```

environment.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EnviromentService {
// The values that are defined here are the default values that can
  // be overridden by env.js

  // API url
  public API_URL = "";

  // Whether or not to enable debug mode

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

I looked in the Git repo the tutorial had liked as well as the other article but to no success.

I tried to call the `env.js` at the earliest point possible again (after the call in the `index.html`) to see if it updates the value.